# The Parallel-Plate Capacitor $C = \epsilon_0A/d$

Tags: physics

I'm working a lab right now where I am given C, A and d and need to re-arrange the formula to find e0

How do I do that? I know dumb question... in a physics 2 class and can't do basic algebra to rearrange a formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\epsilon_0 = \frac{Cd}{A}$$

You should really format your questions a bit more nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You have:
$$C=\varepsilon_0\cdot \frac{A}{d}$$
Now, try dividing both sides by $\frac{A}{d}$ (Multiply both sides by $\frac{d}{A}$ if you prefer, they are the same) and you will see that everything cancels on the RHS except for $\varepsilon_0$.

Comment: Yes thank you, I have it written down showing the work but couldn't get the formatting in here